# Where can I find official information about a recent crash in Mexico?

Tags: helicopter, accidents, accident-investigation, mexico

I have heard about [a helicopter crash involving an Agusta A 109 in Mexico](https://www.cnn.com/2018/12/25/americas/puebla-state-governor-helicopter-crash-investigation/index.html), that seems to be causing some turmoil due to the deaths of a newly-elected governor and her husband. Is there any info about what happened, metars, logs or something?

Aviation herald does not have any info about it.

Comment: This happened less than 24 hours ago, you may be able to look up Metars for the area (if there is a historical weather service for the area), but they won't be releasing any kind of report, logs, pilot history, etc, for quite some time.

Comment: Suggest you check [here](https://www.pprune.org/rotorheads/616620-mexican-governor-senator-husband-down-helicopter-crash-24-12-2018-a.html) in the next few days.  The ICAO Annex 13 investigating country is Mexico, who are not quite as eager to please public curiosity as some other reporting states ...

Comment: [Current investigation status](https://www.gob.mx/cms/uploads/attachment/file/431172/Investigaci_n_del_Accidente_A_reo_en_Puebla.pdf). Update, search for "XA-BON" [here](https://www.gob.mx/busqueda).

Comment: @mins, when You just post the link I give a fast view and few time later was deleted,  It seems to the info was reserved by the Transport Ministry, so it looks something suspicious.

Comment: "*You just post the link I give a fast view and few time later was deleted*". The two links above still work and the domain gob.mx is the [portal of the Mexican administration](https://www.gob.mx/en/what-is-gobmx).

Comment: @mins, I didnt mean as a complain, Indeed there are certain articles, but there were one that started to read but later there werent anymore.

Comment: and as far as I can read Spanish (not much), the info was reserved as matter of national security, and there were politicians arguing this was not an accident, and the aviation herald didnt show any info in the date nor later.